# BlackBerry 10 Cascades. How do I make a long running headless app terminate itself?

Tags: qt, qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I'm making a BB10 app with a headless component that's normally supposed to run nonstop, except when a certain field in its QSettings changes (to save battery power).

I tried looking everywhere for the documentation. But I still can't find out how to make a headless app terminate itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can get notified every time your settings file change using [QFileSystemWatcher](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/qfilesystemwatcher.html) and calling `bb::Application::instance()->quit()` when a certain QSettings value changes. Here's [an example from BlackBerry](https://blackberry.github.io/Cascades-Samples/headlesserviceui.html) that uses QFileSystemWatcher in headless to get notification whenever the QSettings file changes.

I prefer using invocation or my own headless communication mechanism though, you can see [an exemple of how I usually deals with terminating the headless app here](https://github.com/RodgerLeblanc/HeadlessTemplate/blob/master/HeadlessTemplateService/src/service.cpp#L94).